# Load part of page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I know that this I can do with function load

```
 $('#result').load('what.html #div-id');
```

But is one problem, in html code is only one `<div id ="example"></div>` and many class, and I not know how to load only one `<div class = "example"></div>`

Comment: if you have many div-s with a class of `example` and want to load just one of them - which one do you want?

Comment: Not I have 1 class example but it is in <div id='example'></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if u understood you correctly but something like

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'what.html',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {

         $(data).find('div.example:first'); //the first div with example-class

         $(data).find('div.example').index(1); //second div using index

         $(data).find('div.example').eq(2); //third div using eq

         $(data).find('div.example:lt(4)'); //first three divs using lt

         $(data).find('div.example').slice(2,4); //div 2,3 and 4 using slice
     }
 });
```

Comment: Interesting,  how to write if I want have `firs div`, `secon div` with `example-class` ?  `<div id='ex'><div id='ex1'><div class='ex2'></div></div></div> `  this correct: `div.example:second:first` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#result').load('what.html .example');
```

When you retrieving just a part of the document you don't necessarily have to use the `id` selector - it can be any valid CSS selector.

So if you have a `div.example` that you want to load - you can use the class selector.

Comment: See I also need `<div id='ex'><div class='ex1'><div id='ex2'></div></div></div>` I need `ex`, `ex1` but not need `ex2`

Comment: I don't think you can exclude a part of the div you're retrieving.. try to rearrange your `what.html`